# Let $T: P_n(R) \to P_n(R)$ be the linear transformation defined by $T(p(x)) = cp(x) - xp'(x)$. For what values of $c$ is $T$ an isomorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T: P_n(R) \to P_n(R)$ be the linear transformation defined by $T(p(x)) = cp(x) - xp'(x)$. For what values of $c$ is $T$ an isomorphism?

Could any one suggests any **hints** to this question?

Comment: Find a basis for $P_n(\mathbb R)$ and write down the corresponding matrix representation.

Answer (score 2):

A basis for $P_n(\mathbb{R})$ is $B=\{1,x,...,x^n\}$. Write a matrix $A$ where each column represents the coordinates of $T$ applied to that basis element. For example,
$$
T(1)=c
$$
so the first column would be $(c,0,...,0)^T$. Then
$$
T(x)=cx-x.
$$
So the second column would be $(0,c-1,...,0)^T$. Find the general pattern and use the properties of determinants of matrices.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with the definition:

$T$ is an isomorphism if it's both injective and surjective.

In both cases, it will be useful to use a basis of $P_n(\mathbb{R})$. Thus, $T$ is injective if $T(p(x))=0$ implies $p(x)=0$.

Take $p(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+...a_nx^n$. Then

$$
T(p(x))=c(a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+...a_nx^n)+x(a_1+2a_2x+...+na_nx^{n-1})
$$
$$
=ca_0 +a_1(c+1)x+a_2(c+2)x^2+...+a_n(c+n)x^n
$$
Now, for what values of $c$ you can be sure that $T$ will be injective? For example, what happens if $c=-1$. And if $c=1$?

For the values for which $c$ is actually injective, can you try something similar to find for which values of $c$ it is also surjective?

Answer (score 0):

Since the vector spaces are finite dimensional, it is sufficient that $T$ have trivial kernel.

So, $T(p)=0 \iff cp(x)=xp'(x)$.  If $p(x)=a_0+\dots+a_nx^n$, then $p'(x)=a_1\dots+na_nx^{n-1}$.  So we get that $ca_i=i\cdot a_i,\,i=0,\dots, n$.

Therefore $T(p)=0\iff c=i$ for each $0\le i\le n$ such that $a_i\ne0$.

Thus we get an isomorphism when we have $c\ne 0,1,\dots,n$.